# Error resolving template [users/list], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to experiment with Thymeleaf and Spring-boot. I have tried with my helloworld controller and it works fine. But when I create a new user controller and trying to play with ModelAndView object I am getting a template engine exception like this:

```
2019-07-23 17:35:43.427 ERROR 22272 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "/users/list": Error resolving template [/users/list], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/users/list], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.resolveTemplate(TemplateManager.java:869) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:607) ~[thymeleaf-3.0.11.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.11.RELEASE]
```

Here is my pom:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.black.spring.boot.eventsharing</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>thymeleaf-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Event Sharing</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf-spring5.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf-spring5.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Here is my controller:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView list(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("userList", userRepository.listUsers());
        model.addAttribute("title", "List users");
        return new ModelAndView("users/list", "userModel", model);
    }
}
```

Here is my html page list.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Thymeleaf Demo!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="~{fragment/header :: header}"></div>
<div th:replace="~{fragment/footer :: footer}"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my project structure:
[image: Project Strucuture]

Can anyone help with this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show the configuration class for your project. 
Thymeleaf it´s not finding your template. The [documentation](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#creating-and-configuring-the-template-engine) says that by default it resolves to this route: "/WEB-INF/templates/", and to make it lookup elsewhere you need to override it. I achieve this by using this class: ThymeleafViewResolver.

Take a look at this code, where I tell the spring application to look on a /templates/ folder based on my application context.

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver htmlViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine(htmlTemplateResolver()));
    resolver.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setViewNames(new String[] {"*.html"});
    return resolver;
}

private ITemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    resolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
}
```

Either this, or as suggested by comment

> Is templates.users a folder with that name, or is it a users folder inside a templates folder?

Check this, as it might be the cause to your issue.

Comment: This is very useful, indeed it is a folder naming issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help! Thymeleaf is very finicky with this naming stuff.